# I am having an "Illegal start of expression" error with user imput

Tags: java

I am trying to get user input, however I am getting
`illegal start of expression`  at:

```
public static String askTheUser() throws IOException
```

Complete code:

Edit: I have made most of the changes you guys suggested so now I have this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class Driver
{

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Dice dice;
    Craps craps;

    userResponse = askTheUser();
    while(userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    {
        craps = new Craps();
        while(!craps.gameOver())
        {
            craps.roll();
            //print out results of roll
        }
        //print out game results: if(craps.gameWon()...
        userResponse.askTheUser();
    }
}

public static String askTheUser() throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
    String data;

    System.out.print("Want to play craps? Yes or No");
    data = dataIn.readLine();
    if(data.equals("y") || data.equals("yes"))
    {
        return "yes";
    }
    else
    {
        return "no";
    }
}
}
```

However I am still getting `cannot find symbol` at `public static String askTheUser() throws IOException`. So might I be missing an import that I don't know of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you declared `askTheUser` method inside **main method**. `rip it` out off the main method.

```
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
       //code that goes inside main
   }
   public static String askTheUser() throws IOException
   {
       // code that goes in askTheUser
   }
```

Comment: Also, you never declare what class keyboard is.

Comment: Okay thanks I did that, now I think I'm missing an import or something because I'm still getting errors. I have the `java.import.io.BufferedReader`. Do I need anything else?

Comment: @mbridges as others have already pointed. what is the type of keyboard ?? iguess you need to declare `BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(Reader)`

Comment: @PremGenError I got rid of the BufferedReader keyboard part, and updated my code.

Comment: @mbridges count the braces properly. you have to seperate `askTheUser()` from `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: @mbridges `askTheUser`  should be outside of `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: @PremGenError Oops I shouldn't have used the word uptaded, I posted my new code below it. I'll delete my old code now.

Comment: did you import `import java.io.IOException;` `import java.io.InputStreamReader;` ??

Comment: Yes. Thank you! Sorry, still picking up Java!

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** write method inside method in `Java`.
But you can have many methods in the same class.

Why? Because of `Java` specifications.. you are simply not allowed to do so.

*Note that you can have an `anonymous inner class` with methods under another method.*

Answer (score 0):

and i don't think that keyboard.readline() works?

use:

```
InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);
in.readLine(); // Convert to string or int needed!
```